# Is a metric's form determined by its signature?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that we define a 4-dimensional vector space over the real field with a metric with signature (3, 1). Is the scalar product map determined only with this information?

For example: a Minowsky space is defined as a space like this with a scalar product defined as

$$ a \cdot b = a_0b_0 - a_1b_1 - a_2b_2 - a_3b_3$$

My question is: could we leave the scalar product out of the definition? Would the (3, 1) metric imply that the scalar product has this form?

Comment: Um... so you're asking if you can leave _the notation for the thing you're defining_ out of the definition? Then it seems that no useful definition is left.

Comment: Not exactly. I am asking if saying that the metric has (3,1) signature somehow restricts the form of the scalar product to the one I mentioned.

I know the converse is true: if I define the metric and the scalar product as having that form then the signature of the metric will be (3, 1). I ask if it works the other way around.

Comment: x @carllacan: Generally saying that the metric has signature means that the scalar product has this form _up to some linear transformation_ of the coordinates.

Comment: Oh, that's nice: the Lorentz transformations are linear, so if you set the metric to be (3, 1) you automatically make your vectors Lorentz invariant. Thank you very much! If you want I'll mark it as the correct answer if you post it as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write the definition in matrix form:
$$ a\cdot b = (a_0\;a_1\;a_2\;a_3)\begin{pmatrix}1\\&-1\\&&-1\\&&&-1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}b_0\\b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{pmatrix} $$

To say that some inner product $\langle a,b\rangle$ has signature $(3,1)$ is to say that the inner product looks like this dot product *up to linear transformations* -- that is, that there is *some* invertible matrix $P$ such that
$$ \langle a,b\rangle = (a_0\;a_1\;a_2\;a_3)P^T \begin{pmatrix}1\\&-1\\&&-1\\&&&-1\end{pmatrix} P \begin{pmatrix}b_0\\b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{pmatrix} $$
([Sylvester's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_law_of_inertia) says that the signature of a symmetric bilinear form according to this definition is unique).

The Lorentz transformations are exactly those that leave the Minkowski dot product unchanged -- that is, $P$ the matrix of a Lorentz transformation if and only if
$$ P^T \begin{pmatrix}1\\&-1\\&&-1\\&&&-1\end{pmatrix} P = \begin{pmatrix}1\\&-1\\&&-1\\&&&-1\end{pmatrix} $$

[Up to minor conventions: some authors don't consider a transformation to be Lorentz if it includes a time reversal and/or a space parity inversion. And some would say $(1,3)$ instead and/or have the time coordinate be the *last* elements in the 4-vectors, and/or invert the signs of the products.]